# What would happen if light was completely blocked from an object?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

Here's the scenario:

There's an object that has been cased with a device that shoots off an 'anti-light' wave (complete reverse of light waves, destructive interference). Say, you have it set up to automatically detect and fire upon a a light wave in that proximity so that no light wave reaches that object.

What would happen? Would the object be unseeable? Or would it be a black space.

I've been wondering what would happen since color is based off of light and black is when all light is absorbed and not reflected, but there is no light reaching that object.

Comment: If you are interested in light there is a series of MIT vdeos which show that for coherence the whole system is involved, not just the light beams but also the lasing source. which absorbs the energy . see https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-006-video-demonstrations-in-lasers-and-optics-spring-2008/demonstrations-in-physical-optics/destructive-interference-2014-where-does-the-light-go/

Answer (score 1):

> There's an object that has been cased with a device that shoots off an 'anti-light' wave (complete reverse of light waves, destructive interference). Say, you have it set up to automatically detect and fire upon a a light wave in that proximity so that no light wave reaches that object.

You've just described a layer of a material which is perfectly absorptive, which surrounds your object. This is precisely how absorption works: the incoming electromagnetic wave excites charge oscillations in the object, and those charge oscillations emit radiation which interferes destructively with the incoming beam.

Since you've encased your object in a fully opaque case, you won't be able to see it from outside.

As to what that will "look like", it depends on whether you have an outer casing that's able to reflect light coming from outside. If you don't, then it will basically look like [vantablack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack).

Comment: "['That,' he said, 'that... is really bad for the eyes.'](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=1494)"